# Javascript execution speed

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

Hey, this question might sound totally idiotic so I am sorry. I am a total noob what comes to these things, but does the iOS javascript executions speed depend on the internet connection or hardware specs?

Comment: Depends on what the javascript is doing. If you're using it to make a call to a server, then they both matter.

Comment: I am pressing a button with javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection can impact AJAX calls speed, but NOT loaded javascript execution speed.

Hardward speed also has an impact on javascript execution speed.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The Internet speed only affects javascript during a request, like an ajax request for example.
What your script is actually doing on the page also affects the speed, for example, if you are using doing many changes at a time like manipulating the css, and moving things in the DOM then you will notice performance leaks. That is because document reflow is expensive.
If you are simply doing calculations you will not have such problems

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser's [JavaScript engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine).

Comment: ...which in turn depends on hardware specs.

Comment: @Rafe, so you're saying that all JavaScript engines between Chrome, IE, Firefox, etc. have the same execution speeds for various JavaScript code fragments if they're executed on the same hardware?

Comment: no, I'm saying that regardless of engine, a faster chip will execute JS faster relative to a slower chip on the same engine.

Comment: @Rafe, seeing that a JavaScript interpreter (JavaScript engine) directly interacts with the JavaScript that Samuli writes, I think it's more informative to say that it depends on the engine than the hardware specs. This is especially true if he's comparing JavaScript across browsers available on iOS. Since the hardware would be the same, the only measurable difference in execution speed would be between the varying JS engines.