# JavaScript execution and Network bandwidth

Tags: javascript, performance

Need help in understanding if JavaScript performance might be impacted by slow network connection. 
I have gone through the [JavaScript execution speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343205/javascript-execution-speed) thread. All though the code runs on a decent hardware (`Lenevo T450s Windows 8.1, 8GB RAM, i7-5600 CPU with clocking @ 2.69 GHz`), Still I see some discrepancies in page load time due to network speed.

With chrome developer tools network throttling option, I tested a single page app and the below are the results.

First attempt (Loading only a specific route)

```
Speed          API load time        Page load time
No throttling    69 Milliseconds      4.06 Seconds
Fast 3G          944 Milliseconds     9.98 Seconds
Slow 3G          3.39 Seconds         26.49 Seconds
```

Second attempt (Page reload)

```
Speed          API load time        Page load time
No throttling    689 Milliseconds      1.5 Minutes
Fast 3G          12 Seconds            2.2 Minutes
Slow 3G          49.6 Seconds          3.3 Minutes
```

Note: The similar kind of results are observed even when on a VPN network.

Any help in understanding is appreciated.

Comment: Network has no bearing on JS unless 1. JS does network requests 2. you count the download of the JS as part of the timing. But it's unknown what your parameters are here.

Comment: If you have asynchronous or network–dependent events (load, DOMReady, etc.), then obviously network speed will affect your application. It should have no bearing on the execution speed of the code itself.

Comment: Hi @VLAZ, My apologies. The 'API load time' above is the time the browser took to fetch the response from the server, The 'page load time' above is the time the browser takes for the rendering the page after the API response has been received from the server. NOTE: After the API load time mentioned above I am not seeing any network activity in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

> [Does] JavaScript performance might be impacted by slow network connection?

No, the speed JavaScript runs at only depends on your hardware and your browser.

But you did not measure performance, you measured the load time of a page. And for sure it loads longer if you have to load the same amount of html, css and JS over a slower connection.

Comment: Hi thanks for your prompt reply. Actually by page load time, I meant the JavaScript execution time (My apologies). Because all the assets and JavaScript files required for the page to work are already downloaded by the browser. In the above table I mentioned after the API request and response there is no network activity recorded in developer tools

Comment: Then you have to provide some more context (what are you measuring exactly and how, what is the code behind it, ...) it is otherwise impossible to draw any conclusion.